# ssh bash -s meets array variable error

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, ssh

The following script throws an error:

```
declare -a service_ports=(22 80 443 445)

ssh root@host 'bash -s' << EOF

export x=0
while [ \$x -le "${#service_ports[@]}" ]
do
  echo Port ${service_ports[\$x]} # ERROR HERE
  x=\$(( \$x + 1 ))
done

EOF
```

When I run this bash script I get:

```
./q.sh: line 6: $x: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "$x")
```

I need to escape the **$x** variable because I use a "**bash -s**" remote shell. When I remove the backslash I only access my local variable and not the one on the server where the script is executed.

Anyone know the solution to access the content of the array?

Answer (score 0):

You can quote the [here document](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument) terminator declaration to avoid having to escape *anything* in the input string (of course that also means you *can't* inject the value of a local variable in the remote script):

```
my_command << 'EOF'
foo $bar
[...]
EOF
```

If you need to inject local variable contents, you could instead go for mixed quotes:

```
my_input='some $literal$ strings'
my_input="${my_input}${my_variable}"
[...]
```

Also, you can simplify your command in several ways:

- You shouldn't have to specify `bash -s` when running a remote command, unless that is different from your default shell.
- There's no point in `export`ing variables which are not used in subsequent *script* calls
- You don't need to `declare -a` when you assign an array literal immediately

Comment: thank you for the answer. but i need to inject the value of a local variable into the remote script. is there a way to accomplish both?